# SQL count query

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005

Hi why doesn't this work in SQL Server 2005?

```
select HALID, count(HALID) as CH from Outages.FaultsInOutages

where CH > 3

group by HALID
```

I get invalid column name 'CH'

---

i think having was the right way to go but still receive the error:
Invalid column name 'CH'.

When running:

select HALID, count(HALID) as CH from Outages.FaultsInOutages 
group by HALID having CH > 3

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can't use the alias in the where clause or having clause, as it isn't processed until AFTER the result set is generated, the proper syntax is

```
SELECT HALID, COUNT(HALID) AS CH
FROM Outages.FaultsInOutages
GROUP BY HALID
HAVING COUNT(HALID) > 3
```

This will group items on HALID, then ONLY return results that have more than 3 entries for the specific HALID

Answer (score 4):

Try

```
select HALID, count(HALID) from Outages.FaultsInOutages 
group by HALID having count(HALID) > 3
```

Your query has two errors:

- Using where an aggregate when grouping by, solved by using having
- Using an alias for an aggregate in the condition, not supported, solved by using the aggregate again